Apex Chart Multiple Legend
Title
How to render different shapes for Legends in ApexCharts in Angular?
Description:
I'm working on Angular application where I'm using Apexcharts to visualize data. I need to customize the legends so that each legend item will display a different shape corresponding to chart series it represents.
I have tried using the 'shape' property in the legend markers suggested by the documentation but I couldn't find the property in the type definitions(apex-types.d.ts).
Question:
How can I render different shapes for each legend item in ApexCharts using Angular? Is there any alternate approach I should consider?
Attaching sandbox link for reference.
https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-column-basic-bm9dd?from-embed=&file=/src/app/app.component.ts
I Tried
I tried by customHTML function which is available in documentation as well as tried shape in sandbox where I couldn't get the expected results.
sample Code
legend: {
show: true,
markers: {
shape: ["line","Circle"],
height: 2
}
}
Expecting:
How can I render different shapes for each legend item in ApexCharts using Angular? Is there any alternate approach I should consider?
